# OS - How are allocated frames for processes?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, frame, paging

Modern operating systems use paging to allocate memory but they need to allocate frames into memory. 
I know Linux uses the buddy system to do it.

What about other OS like Windows, Unix or Solaris? Are best/worst/next/first and quick fit used?

Is paging used to allocate kernel's memory?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

System use different methods to allocate memory and may use different method in different contexts.

Question 2:

A modern kernel usually maintains memory using a page table (segment table). There is generally a mixture between paged memory and non-paged memory. I/O requests, may be non-paged while user-mode page tables may be paged.